# ldapjs with ldaps - Do I need to configure additional params?

Tags: node.js, ssl, active-directory, ldap, ldapjs

I've used a nodejs module called bluepages that internally uses ldapjs for LDAP based authentication.

I checked the code and found that it was connecting on `ldap://ldap-domain.com` from which I figured it was insecure.

I modified it to the following `ldaps://ldap-domain.com:636`. Whether this will ensure the connection is secure is something I'm not sure about. Do I need to provide additional params?

I was told that ***certificates have to be imported***, etc to ensure a secure connection.If thats the case how do I do so?

Comment: 636 should be LDAPS. Does it work? Importing certificates is only required if the LDAP server's certificate is self-signed or signed by an untrusted CA.

Comment: It does work, the authentication goes through. The signing part is something I lack clarity on.

Does ldaps always guarantee a secure connection even if the connection goes through.